# To show that Möbius transformation is holomorphic on $\Bbb C_{\infty}$

Tags: complex-analysis, mobius-transformation

A function $f: \Bbb C_{\infty}\to \Bbb C_{\infty}$ is biholomorphic if $f$ is bijective, holomorphic and $f^{-1}$ is holomorphic on $\Bbb C_{\infty}$, where $\Bbb C_{\infty}$ is the one point compactification on the complex plane.

Now I want to show that a Möbius transformation $f: \Bbb C_{\infty}\to \Bbb C_{\infty}$ is defined by $$f=\frac{az+b}{cz+d}$$, $a,b,c,d\in \Bbb C$, is holomorphic on $\Bbb C_{\infty}$.

It may have two cases, namely $c=0$ and $c\ne 0$.

If $c=0$, then $f=\frac{a}{d}z+\frac{c}{d}$ is holomorphic on $\Bbb C_{\infty}$ and $f(\infty)=\infty$.

Consider the function $g(z)=f(1/z)$, then $g$ has a pole at $0$. But I have no idea how to use this to show that $f$ is holomorphic at $\infty$.

If $c\neq 0$, then $f$ is holomorphic on $\Bbb C-\{\frac{-d}{c}\}$ and $f(\infty)=\frac{a}{c}$, $f(\frac{-d}{c})=\infty$.

I know that $\lim_{z\to 0}|g(z)|=\frac{a}{c}$, so $g$ is holomorphic at $0$ by Riemann removable singularty theorem, and $f$ is holomorphic at $\infty$.

But I have no idea to prove $f$ is holomorphic at $-\frac{d}{c}$.

In short, when $c=0$, how to prove that $f$ is holomorphic at $\infty$? When $c\ne0$, how to prove that $f$ is holomorphic at $-\frac{d}{c}$ ?

Thanks for your helping.

Comment: My class note states that $Aut(\Bbb C_{\infty})$ is equal to the set of all Möbius transformations on $\Bbb C_{\infty}$. I'm not sure what I have missed.

Comment: What is $\mathbb{C}_{\infty}$? Is it a compactification of the complex plane?

Comment: Yes, the one point compactification on the complex plane

Comment: We are viewing the Möbius transformations as maps to the Riemann sphere, not as maps to the complex plane. As such, they are holomorphic on the whole Riemann sphere. Such a map $f$ is holomorphic at a point $z_0$ that is mapped to $\infty$ iff $1/f$ is holomorphic at $z_0$. (The Riemann sphere is the simplest compact Riemann surface, with charts $z \mapsto z$ on the complement of $\infty$ and $z \mapsto 1/z$ on the complement of $0$.)

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy The only holomorphic functions from $\Bbb C_{\infty}$ to $\Bbb C$ are constants, which is the usual way "holomorphic" is understood, but I believe the term "holomorphic" has broader usage in the context of Riemann surfaces, in which case the invertible holomorphic functions from $\Bbb C_{\infty}$ to itself are the Mobius transformations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are three fundamental types of Möbius transforms: rotation-dilations

$$z\mapsto az,$$

Translations

$$z\mapsto z+b,$$

and inversions

$$z\mapsto\frac{1}{z}.$$

All Möbius transformations are compositions of these three fundamental transformations, so it is enough to show that these three are biholomorphic as functions $\mathbb C_\infty\to\mathbb C_\infty$. And since the inverse of a Möbius transformation is again a Möbius transformation, it is even enough to just show that they are simply holomorphic. Biholomorphicity follows automatically.

So rotation-dilations and translations are obviously holomorphic on $\mathbb C$. We only need to consider their behavior at $\infty$. A function $\varphi:\mathbb C_\infty\to\mathbb C_\infty$ with $\varphi(\infty)=\infty$ is complex differentiable at $\infty$ if $\tilde\varphi(z):=\frac{1}{\varphi(\frac{1}{z})}$ is complex differentiable at $0$. For rotation-dilations and translations, this can be seen by plugging in and looking at the resulting functions.

Now the inversion. On $\mathbb C\backslash\{0\}$, it is obviously holomorphic. So only its behavior at $0$ and $\infty$ needs to be examined further. A function with $\varphi(0)=\infty$, is complex differentiable at $0$ if $\frac{1}{\varphi (z)}$ is complex differentiable at $0$. Similarly, if $\varphi(\infty)=0$, then it is complex differentiable at $\infty$ if $\varphi(\frac{1}{z})$ is complex differentiable at $0$. Both of these are fulfilled (just plug it in), so we're done.

Comment: In my text book, the definition of holomorphic at infinity is: $f(z)$ is holomorphic at infinity if $f(\frac{1}{z})$ is holomorphic at $0$. If $f=az$ is a rotation-dilation, and $f(\infty)=\infty$, then $f(\frac{1}{z})\to \infty$ as $z\to 0$. How could I state that $f$ is holomorphic at $\infty$ from that?

Comment: This is only true for functions $\mathbb C_\infty\to\mathbb C$. But here we have $\mathbb C_\infty$ as the codomain, so we need a different approach. There is a pretty general but slightly complicated one which requires some differential geometry, but essentially we need to transport both the point $z$ at which we evaluate $f$, and its image $f(z)$ back to the complex plane to talk about complex differentiability. We transport $z=\infty$ to $0$ by inverting it, and then we transport $f(1/z)=\infty$ to $0$ again by also inverting it, giving us $1/f(1/z)$ to work with.

Comment: It looks like my lecture note has not mention that, it just say that we can consider in the similar way. Thanks for your explanation